# How to find the Supplier number for those suppliers who supply all parts that are supplied by another by supplier in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find the SNO for the Supplier that supplied all parts that is supplied that by another by Supplier.

For example, I have

```
(S1, P1, 100), 
(S1, P2, 200), 
(S2, P1, 300), 
(S2, P2, 100),
(S3, P1, 400),
(S4, P1, 100), 
(S4, P2, 200)
```

So I am trying to find the SNO of the suppliers that supplied all the parts supplied by S2 not one part. Therefore, the answer should be S1 & S4 but I could not get the SQL Query to solve this. I hope I could get some help.

Comment: Your question is (at least to me) not understandable. Try rephrasing.

Comment: It's understandable to me too.
You want the suppliers that supply all S2 parts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how I achieved the result:

```
create table MyTable (
  Supplier varchar(20),
  Part varchar(20),
  SomeOrder int
)

insert into MyTable values 
('S1', 'P1', 100),
('S1', 'P2', 200), 
('S2', 'P1', 300), 
('S2', 'P2', 100),
('S3', 'P1', 400),
('S4', 'P1', 100), 
('S4', 'P2', 200)
---------------------------

-- temporary table to store all parts of a supplier
CREATE TABLE #tmp (Part varchar(20))

-- put your desired provider here
declare @Supplier varchar(20) = 'S2'

-- select all parts of this supplier
insert into #tmp
select Part from MyTable where Supplier = @Supplier

-- count how many parts this supplier has
declare @partCount int
select @partCount = count(*) from #tmp

-- select all suppliers that have all the parts (i.e. count = @partCount)
select innerTbl.Supplier from (
    select m.Supplier, m.Part
    from MyTable m
    inner join #tmp t on t.Part = M.Part
  ) innerTbl
 group by innerTbl.Supplier
 having Count(innerTbl.Supplier) = @partCount 
 and innerTbl.Supplier <> @Supplier
```

Comment: What if S2 is not to be included since it's this one I'm checking, pls can you remove S2 from the result provided

Comment: just add this condition: AND innerTbl.Supplier <> @Supplier

Comment: The error says: "I must declare the scalar variable '@Supplier' "

Comment: just remove the 'GO' from the script

Comment: Thanks. Works well

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without temporary tables.  Assuming there are no duplicates in your table:

```
select sp.supplier
from supplierparts sp join
     supplierparts sp2
     on sp.part = sp2.part and sp2.supplier = 2
group by sp.supplier
having count(*) = (select count(*) from supplierparts sp3 where sp3.supplier = 2);
```

If you wanted exact equality (that is, supplying `P3` would invalidate the supplier), then:

```
select sp.supplier
from supplierparts sp left join
     supplierparts sp2
     on sp.part = sp2.part and sp2.supplier = 2                    
group by sp.supplier
having count(*) = (select count(*) from supplierparts sp3 where sp3.supplier = 2) and
       count(*) = count(sp2.part);
```

Comment: Please what are you selecting, can you explain "sp.supplier" because it's giving me error while trying to test your query